# Include a picture in mailto:

Tags: iphone, mailto

I'm interested in placing a picture (along with some text) in a prepared email for the user to send off. Is there any way to use mailto: to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The `mailto:` scheme does not support attachment. (See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html).

If you write an app you can attach an image with `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: MFMailoComposeViewController was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Is there a corresponding interface for sending text messages, I wonder?

Comment: Hello, this is quite an old question, but iOS now supports the `<img>` tag in the body of the mailto link. The image and website protocol must match though (if your website uses `https`, the image should also be `https`).

Answer (score 1):

No, mailto: is just a HREF target for the A tag, and just instructs the operating system to open the mail browser to a specific location (with subject).  To send a custom email on click of a link, you'll need server side code, such as PHP (sendmail) or Ruby (ActionMailer)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is link to an image, like this:

```
<a href="mailto:?to=joe@example.com&body=http://www.mydomain.com/myimage.jpg">test</a>
```